# I want to copy some names from another file into an array based on certain criterion

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy some names from another file into an array based on certain criterion, and paste the array in the calling file.
The code I wrote doesn't work. What did I miss here?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
    Workbooks.Open ("D:\Slave.xlsx") 
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False 
    Windows("Slave.xlsx").Activate 
    Sheet1.Activate 
    For i = 1 To 5 
        names(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) 
    Next 
    Windows("Slave.xlsx").Close 
    Sheet1.Activate 
    For n = 1 To 5 
        Sheet1.Cells(n + 10, 1) = names(n) 
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive than "doesn't work"?

Comment: By "names" do you mean entries in a workbook's Names collection? I suspect that you don't -- in which case this is all confusing. What is names()? Where is it declared?

Comment: You need to qualify the first instance of `Sheet1` with a workbook object, otherwise it will default to the class that exists in the `ThisWorkbook` object. In short, change it to `ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myNames() As String
    ReDim myNames(1 To 5)
    Workbooks.Open ("D:\Slave.xlsx")
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    Windows("Slave.xlsx").Activate
    Sheet1.Activate
    For i = LBound(myNames) To UBound(myNames)
        myNames(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
    Next
    Windows("Slave.xlsx").Close
    Sheet1.Activate
    For n = LBound(myNames) To UBound(myNames)
        Sheet1.Cells(n + 10, 1) = myNames(n)
    Next
End Sub
```

I don't know if `Names` per se is a reference to restricted access property or you just didn't declare it beforehand, so I changed it in your script to `myNames()`. The intake and output now work by a single dynamic declaration possibly saving you some headache in the future.
For the sole purpose of showing off I also created a more PC sub that won't flash as much and may run slightly faster (especially if the dataset is larger):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myNames() As Variant, wb(1) As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
ReDim myNames(1 To 5)
On Error GoTo wsOrwbDoesntExist
Set wb(0) = ThisWorkbook
Set wb(1) = Workbooks.Open("D:\Slave.xlsx")
    wb(1).Windows(1).Visible = False
Set ws = wb(1).Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'ActiveWindow.Visible = False 'what's this?
For i = LBound(myNames) To UBound(myNames)
    myNames(i) = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value2
Next

wb(1).Close (SaveChanges = False)
Set ws = wb(0).Worksheets("Sheet1")

For n = LBound(myNames) To UBound(myNames)
    ws.Cells(n + 10, 1).Value2 = myNames(n)
Next
Exit Sub
wsOrwbDoesntExist:
MsgBox "Referenced workbook or worksheet may not exist." & vbNewLine & "Please run this sub in debug mode."
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant but `Worksheets("Sheet1")` seems like a more appropriate declaration for a sheet.